# How can I use Socket in Blazor Client-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I wanna try to connect to a machine by Blazor Client-side.

I installed the Nuget package System.Net.Sockets to achieve it.

Here is the code:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject HttpClient Http
@using System.Net.Sockets;
@using System.Net;

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>



@code {    
    Socket S; 
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.200.111");
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 23);
            try
            {
                S = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                S.Connect(ipEndPoint);

                Byte[] inBuffer = new Byte[1024];
                S.Send(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("PEY" + Environment.NewLine));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

When the breakpoint runs at

```
S = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

It reports an error only with this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to do this.

This is a Browser / JavaScript security feature, sockets are not allowed.

You will have to use WebSockets (SignalR) or the HttpClient. HttpClient has been re-implemented in Blazor to go through JavaScript.

When you need to access an existing service with sockets you will need a server back-end to do that. Consider Blazor/Server or Blazor/Wasm Hosted.

Comment: It seems there are many differences between Socket and HttpClient. I tried to send the data via post method and the machine does not reply any.

Comment: And also Socket does not separate from post/get/delete and any other method.

Comment: No. You will have to take stock and rethink how you can accomplish what you want with what is available. I have added two options.

Comment: @MelonNG Sockets work at the TCP level, far lower than protocols like HTTP or FTP.  On a browser, applications can't access the network directly, they have to go through the browser. In Blazor WASM the HttpClient class doesn't make any HTTP requests itself, it asks the browser to do so. That's btw why gRPC can't be used by browsers and we had to wait for gRPC-Web