# TCP connection to client internal port with Blazor server app

Tags: c#, tcp, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to make a website that connects to a clients internal server through a TCP connection in order to get a stream of data from an internal server in the clients computer (at a specific port).

There is a 3rd party program that when running simulations creates a 'telemetry server' at a specific port in the clients computer. I want my website to connect to that port on the clients computer and do stuff (plots) with that output.

I read about Blazor server-side app and though I give it a try since I know C# and I already wrote a program to graph said telemetry output data in C#. Now I want to make my program available to others though a website.

My program connects through **System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient** without problem. I even tested the connection on Blazor server-side app and it connects when the server is running on my computer.

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpclnt = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
state = "Connecting.....";
tcpclnt.Connect(myIp, 15151); // Telemetry server in port 15151
stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
```

**The problem** is when I host my Blazor website in Azure, it is not longer able to connect. I tried writing my public IP in `myIp` and it doesn't work.

Unfortunately I don't get info error output from Blazor since the website just freezes with "An error has occurred..." message.

I don't know much about this (TCP connections, web connection rules, ports..) and would appreciate any leads on what could be wrong or if it is even possible.

EDIT:
I'm using server-side as suggested here since a client-side app wont be allowed to connect [How can I use Socket in Blazor Client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906292/how-can-i-use-socket-in-blazor-client-side)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Azure web app?

You might want to consider adding Azure Network Gateways to handle Routing rules. I think all apps and VM's in Azure need a application gateway to communicate outside of the Azure subnet.